# Starting Speech Recognition with CreateProcess() in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process, accessibility

I need help with my simple program, which tries to create a new process running Speech recognition.
When I open cmd and type in the command `C:\Windows\Speech\Common\sapisvr.exe -SpeechUX` then the speech recognition would successfully start. It will start even when running through `system(C:\\Windows\\...)` which basically just mimics cmd.
However, when creating the new process with CreateProcess() as below, the function fails. If I put whole path and argument into second parameter `CreateProcess(NULL, TEXT("C:\\Windows...\\sapisvr.exe -SpeechUX"), ...)`, then I get a runtime exception: *Access violation writing location*

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    if (!CreateProcess(
    TEXT("C:\\Windows\\Speech\\Common\\sapisvr.exe"), //Module name
    TEXT(" -SpeechUX"),     //command line params
    NULL,       //Process attributes
    NULL,       //Thread attributes
    FALSE,      //Handle inheritance
    0,          //No creation flags
    NULL,       //Use parent's environment
    NULL,       //Use parent's starting directory
    &si,        //Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi ))      //Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    {
        printf("error creating process\n");
        return 1;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

First I tried to test CreateProcess function with running notepad with an argument to open an existing file. When I put path to notepad.exe to first parameter and name of the file to the command line parameter, it didn't recognise it and opened a new file instead.

This whole applies as well to trying to run msconfig.exe from my program, which doesn't take any parameters, so I guess the problem is somewhere else, I just have no idea where.
I searched the web and none of the answers actually worked for me. I'm working in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 8.1.

Thanks for help.

Comment: The second parameter to CreateProcess must be a writeable buffer, not a string-literal.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: only when calling `CreateProcessW()`, not when calling `CreateProcessA()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function has a second argument as an `LPTSTR`.  For the `CreateProcessW` version of this function, this must be a writeable buffer, not a string literal.  Thus your program's behavior is undefined.  Since you are getting an access violation writing to a location when calling `CreateProcess`, we will assume that `CreateProcess` is being mapped to `CreateProcessW`.

At the link posted, here is the quote:

> The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter **cannot be a pointer to read-only memory** (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.

So the fix is simply define an array, not a literal:

```
TCHAR commandParam[] = TEXT(" -SpeechUX");

if (!CreateProcess(TEXT("C:\\Windows\\Speech\\Common\\sapisvr.exe"), 
                   commandParam,
                   ...
   }
```

or if passing NULL as the first argument:

```
TCHAR commandParam[] = TEXT("C:\\Windows\\Speech\\Common\\sapisvr.exe");
//...
if (!CreateProcess(NULL, commandParam, ...
```

Also, if `CreateProcess` returns an error, you should call [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and optionally [FormatMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), to get the error that occurred, and not simply output that there is an error.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. But I am still getting _error creating process_. Even trying to put the whole path and argument into the commandParam, it does not work.

Comment: What is the error?  Did you call `GetLastError`?  And did you try placing the entire command *in an array* and not as a string-literal for the second parameter (and leaving the first parameter as NULL)?

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct path? Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890746/how-to-use-or-expand-environment-variables-in-a-command-instantiated-by-createpr

Comment: Yes, I tried to put it whole into the second parameter, no avail. The error I get is 2 - cannot find specified file. But the executable is literally there. Can it be some 32/64 bit problem?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The error I get is not 2 (had typo in path), but 740 - requires elevation. But it shouldn't. Speech recognition can be run without admin privileges.

Comment: @MiragePV -- What if you typed in the command you're trying to run at a command prompt?  Either elevated or non-elevated -- what happens?  Also, maybe this should be a new topic question, since the access violation has been addressed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for help, I'll address this newfound problem elsewhere.

Comment: The first solution doesn't work. *SapiSvr.exe* expects the path to the binary as its first argument, so you need to replicate it in your *commandParam* array. That's the reason, why you would normally never specify both application name and command line. Your second solution is almost correct. It happens to work in this case, but in general you should always quote the pathname.

Comment: @IInspectable You can post that as an answer to complement the answer I gave wrt the access violation.